# Error: Gradle: Execution failed "Running /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt failed"

Tags: gradle, android-studio

For some reason Android Studio has started giving me the above error when I try to compile my app. As far as a know nothing has changed, it worked one day but not the next.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem? I've tried reinstalled Android Studio and hat didn't help.

Comment: Anyone else who has this problem, the problem was one of my assets had an uppercase letter in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because one or more of your asset names have unsupported characters present.

Replace all capitals with lowercase letters. 
Replace all spaces and dashes with an under-bar/underscore. 
AND to be safe, remove all numbers too.

Another suggestion I've seen going around is to make sure your SDK is up to date, but from my own experience it has always been the names of imported assets.